# WordPress fopen getting directory link

Tags: wordpress, fopen, fwrite

I'm using fwrite to create an html file in a folder within my plugin. The following code now allows me to write to the folder, but the link it tries to open is the full system path.

```
function buildFrameFile($html, $filename){
    $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $filename= $DOCUMENT_ROOT. '/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/html/' . $filename . ".html";
 $fh = fopen($filename, 'a');//open file and create if does not exist
 fwrite($fh, $html);//write data
 fclose($fh);//close file

 return $filename;
 }
```

The path it now opens is:

```
/var/chroot/home/content/##/########/html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/html/79dda339bad8e65c425e580d62f41fa1.html
```

I need it to open from here:

```
/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/html/79dda339bad8e65c425e580d62f41fa1.html
```

I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I ended up changing the code from:

```
function buildFrameFile($html, $filename){
    $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $filename= $DOCUMENT_ROOT. '/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/html/' . $filename . ".html";
 $fh = fopen($filename, 'a');//open file and create if does not exist
 fwrite($fh, $html);//write data
 fclose($fh);//close file

 return $filename;
 }
```

To:

```
    function buildFrameFile($html, $filename){
    $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $filename2= $DOCUMENT_ROOT. '/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/html/' . $filename . ".html";
 $fh = fopen($filename2, 'a');//open file and create if does not exist
 fwrite($fh, $html);//write data
 fclose($fh);//close file

 return $filename;
 }
```

This way the file gets saved to the folder and only returns the actual name of the file not the whole link to the file.

Then in my header I changed the code from:

```
header("Location: /confirm" . $nvp_str . "&filename=" . $filename);
```

To:

```
header("Location: /confirm?" . $nvp_str . "&filename=" . '/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/html/' . $filename . ".html");
```

and the iframe in my page calls the value of &filename which then returns the proper link to my file created and it loads perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can rely on Wordpress' defines (or functions) to determinate the paths without any dirty hacks:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Available_Functions
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Constants

Then again you can check things using PHP functions like `file_exists()`, `is_dir()`, `is_writable()`:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

To avoid complex fopen, fwrite, fclose handlers, you can go for `file_put_contents()` function there too. Either in appending or overwriting mode:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Not sure how relevant, but keep in mind if this is written by the webserver, you need to make sure the directory has write permissions there. Easiest way would be `chmod 777 directory` from shell, or `SITE CHMOD 777 directory` from FTP.

Comment: I'm not sure that helps me. I have tried chmod 777 on the directory and using fwrite() as well as file_put_contents() and even had the $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; set to the plugin path. But, it only writes to the folder if I use $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; Which of course then calls the full system path to the file which then can't be accessed. The file does get added to the folder though.

Comment: Is your HTTP server running from chroot as well?

Comment: The hosting service is godaddy.com and I don't know if it runs from chroot. I don't see anything showing that it does until I run the script above.

Comment: This is most odd. What happens if you try printing out the `dirname(__FILE__);`?

Comment: If it do that, it starts out at /home/ rather than /var/chroot/home/

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely connected to weird godaddy's setup.
You can find more information here: http://www.quest4.org/etc/godaddy_path.htm

There's also a similiar issue posted here:
[WordPress's plugins_url() function not working on shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391522/wordpresss-plugins-url-function-not-working-on-shared-hosting)